# Turn off all notifications for Notification Suggestions

Tags: windows-11, notifications

From time to time I get this notification from Windows 11:

[image: Notification Suggestion]

If I want to turn it off (by clicking on <kbd>...</kbd>), the option is gray:

[image: Notification Suggestion after clicking ...]

So, how to turn it off?

---

The following settings are turned off under my *System* > *Notifications* > *Additional settings*:

- *Show the Windows welcome experience after updates and when signed in to show what's new and suggested*
- *Suggest ways to get the most out of Windows and finish setting up this device*
- *Get tips and suggestions when using Windows*

Comment: Since this has 12 up-votes *so far*, and no answer or (other) comment, I'd guess this is a bug in Windows 11, and might be reported as such to MS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Windows Push Notifications User Service refers to this functionality as **SmartOptOut**.

It's difficult to test because SmartOptOut runs on a timer, and modifying the saved timer state in the registry does not seem to induce the "Turn off notifications" toasts for experimentation, but here are some ideas. I'm still testing them because of how long and unpredictable verification is, but I'll update this answer if I learn anything new.

**Current status:** I have enabled Ideas 1 and 2 on three computers on 2024-03-15 and haven't seen any Notification Suggestions since. Will update if this changes.

## Idea 1: disable notification in registry

It seems to be possible to "Turn off all notifications for Notification Suggestions" with this registry change:

```reg
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Windows.ActionCenter.SmartOptOut]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
```

## Idea 2: allow notifications to be disabled in UI

Alternatively, if you want to disable it through the Settings app GUI, you can set the following value. However, this is a more circuitous path that doesn't work any better, it's just a different route to the same state as Idea 1.

```reg
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppUserModelId\Windows.ActionCenter.SmartOptOut]
"ShowInSettings"=dword:00000001
```

Then go to Settings > System > Notifications, and under "Notifications from apps and other senders," turn "Notification Suggestions" off.

[image: turned off in Settings list]

[image: turned off in Settings]

You could also wait for the "We noticed you haven't opened these in a while" notification to appear again and click "Turn off all notifications for Notification Suggestions" in the … menu (which will no longer be disabled as it was in the question's screenshot):

[image: turn off enabled in toast]

However, this key is only writable by the TrustedInstaller user, so you have to give yourself permissions to write to it, or run `regedit.exe` as TrustedInstaller (for example, using [WinAero Tweaker](https://winaero.com/winaero-tweaker/), [ExecTi](https://winaero.com/execti/), or [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)).

## Idea 3: slow down timer

You can modify the frequency at which SmartOptOut runs, so you may be able to make it run so infrequently that it practically never runs. I have used this to make it run faster for testing, so slower should work too.

```reg
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\SmartOptOut]
"InitialTimerCooldown"=hex(b):ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff
"PeriodicTimerCooldown"=hex(b):ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff
```

These changes set the interval between the WpnUserService starting and the first SmartOptOut check, and the interval between subsequent checks, to the maximum 64-bit unsigned long value. This seems to be interpreted as a duration in seconds, which equates to about 585 billion years.