# Disable Windows Notification Suggestions

Tags: windows, windows-11

This thing is a relatively recent addition (less than a year), if my memory is correct:

[image]

This message shows up somewhat rarely, but is it possible to make that a never?

---

PS: Searching online gives me results for something completely unrelated:

[image]

Which I already have disabled anyway.

Comment: You could in *Settings > System > Notifications & actions* turn on "Do not disturb" so that "Notifications will be sent directly to notification center" and so will not popup. Have a look also at "Turn on do not disturb automatically" and *Settings > System > Focus*, if they suite your purpose. ([link](https://www.theverge.com/23819943/windows-pc-notification-control-change-how-to).)

Comment: @harrymc That doesn't sound like what I want, I want the notifications to show up, except for that particular notification. I don't want a notification that tells me I'm ignoring notifications - I know that, I want to see it even if I don't do anything about it.

Comment: Astoundingly I can't find anything online about this. Infuriating. Constantly getting "suggestions" to turn off notifications for things like the Clock app, where you DON'T INTERACT WITH THE NOTIFICATIONS. Of course I'm not going to click on my TIMER NOTIFICATION when it's DONE, I'll just turn it off. Worthless. It is NOT what harrymc suggested, that is a misunderstanding of the new feature added and cripples the notifications across the system. At that point just turn them off.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/1820188/turn-off-all-notifications-for-notification-suggestions